# Dropshipping partner invoices

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice, dropshipping

We have a magento webshop. Sometimes another shop orders an item and wants us to deliver it to the client. The client orders from the partner's website (not magento - doesn't have a connector to our site), and then the partner manually orders the products on our site under the client's name and address, using his discount code.

When we print an invoice for such an order, our name is displayed on the invoice, plus the discount we give to this partner. One option is to create another shop in a subdomain with its own invoice header etc. This leaves the problem of the discount still unsolved, although I could probably make it so that invoices for this shop don't display discounts.

Looking for dropshipping options for Magento I find modules that work the other way around, for clients that order products on our website and we let it ship by another partner.

I would like to know if there are better solutions. Now we have only one dropshipping partner, but we want to promote this option and use it more often. So is there a more easy way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Magento is not intended to be used this way. What you want is EITHER write an invoice in name of your partner and pass it into their system, or request an invoice from them to put into the box OR write an invoice in your name and add all the information. If you add invoices in YOUR name (and not your partners) without the discount, I think you swallowed up your accounting. At least in Germany you would, so this is a bad idea (I think).

So as I said in the begining, I see two options either write a correct (as you want to have it) invoice in the name of your partner (however it is created) or send the invoice you create.

The problem here is not the invoice, it is the workflow. The invoice you create should be send to your partner and they should sent an invoice to your customer.